# Deleting row from Java ResultSet and not from underlying database

Tags: java, resultset, delete-row

Is there a way in Java to delete a row just from a result set and not from underlying database? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the [`CachedRowSet`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/javax/sql/rowset/CachedRowSet.html). It allows you to create a disconnected `ResultSet` and operate without affecting the database.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're iterating through your ResultSet and filtering rows as you go?

I would say either move the filtering to the SQL statement if you can, otherwise copy the ResultSet into a List, either of objects of rowtype or just Map's if you'd rather not, then call list.remove(row) as you go.

You can't remove rows or update a ResultSet, you'd have to use a CachedRowSet like VAShhh suggests.

Comment: thnx matao for your reply,, actually my resultset is huge 100 mb or more I need to iterate it and create other formatted java objects so it takes a huge amount of memory when i execute the method, that why i want to remove the resultset row when i iterate over it and at same time do not want it to be deleted from DB

Comment: the deleteRow method in cachedrowset also deletes the current row from the underlying database just like the ResultSet do. is it required to call acceptChanges method to delete current row from the database as well or not ? if not than i think my problem is solved.

Comment: do you need to have Random Access to the ResultSet? If not I would suggest paging the ResultSet, then you could get 1000 rows, process them, get the next 1000 etc. But if you're building up a dictionary of already "seen" rows then you won't be able to do that.
If your data is such that you really can't do paging, then the next suggestion would be some kind of a temp table in the DB, write the results into it and do the processing there. It really depends on the characteristics of your data...

Comment: for example, you could set fetch size (setFetchSize(int size) on the ResultSet to 1000, then the ResultSet will only get 1,000 rows at a time from the DB, pulling more as needed.
http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html

Answer (score 0):

You can solve that problem by setting `setAutoCommit()` on your connection object to false, e.g `conn.setAutoCommit(false)`.

Then perform all your deletes, after which you call `rollback()` on the connection object: `conn.rollback()`. This will reverse all the delete that you made and keep your database at the original state.